# Converting lambda expression into an expression tree

Tags: linq, lambda

From C# in depth:

> Not all lambda expressions can be converted to expression trees. You
>   can’t convert a lambda with a block of statements ( even just one
>   return statement ) into an expresion tree --> it has to be in the form
>   that just evaluates a single expression.

Since Linq-to-Object statements don't get converted into expression tree objects, the lambda expressions used with Linq-to-Object operators can contain a block of statements

```
        string[] count = { "one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five ", "six " };
        IEnumerable<int> result = count.Select(item =>
                               {
                                   Console.WriteLine(item);
                                   return item.Length;
                               });
        foreach (int i in result);
```

OUTPUT:

```
one two three four five six
```

I haven't yet started learning Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities, but I assume lambda expressions used with LINQ statements that operate on `IQueryable<T>` can only ever contain a single expression, due to restristion that only a single expression can be converted into an expression tree?

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not just that they can only contain a single expression - it's can't be a *statement lambda* at all. Even a block like this:

```
var result = query.Select(item => { return item.Length; });
```

would be invalid for LINQ to SQL. It would have to be expressed as:

```
var result = query.Select(item => item.Length);
```

(I've just noticed that that's the bit of the book you quoted. Oh well - it shows I'm consistent :)

Note that as of .NET 4, expression trees themselves *do* have the ability to contain blocks, but the C# compiler can't translate statement lambdas into that kind of expression tree. There are other restrictions too, but they rarely cause problems.

This is specified in section 4.6 of the C# 4 spec:

> Not all anonymous functions can be represented as expression trees. For instance, anonymous functions with statement bodies and anonymous functions containing assignment expressions cannot be represented. In these cases, a conversion still exists, but will fail at compile-time.

Comment: Now, what on earth would *you* know about something mentioned in **C# in Depth**?  Oh, never mind.

Comment: @Jon: It suddenly occurred to me how very related this question is to that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405423/do-at-compile-time-linq-to-objects-statements-also-get-translated-into-expressio *wink wink*

Comment: Jon, what do you mean when you say it can't be a statement lambda? The question shows sample code using a statement lambda and it outputs the correct values.

Comment: @Nick: It uses a statement lambda... But converts it into a delegate, not an expression tree.

Comment: Expression tree does not execute code rather than generating data, where later you can compile it back to code.

Comment: @wajatimur: I'm not entirely sure what the point of your comment was... could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, they can only ever contain a single expression.